# global variable is showing blank always in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created a global variable in jquery. then i created a function in which i making jquery get call and setting the response var to global variable. when i am doing console.log to that global var, it is showing blank always. the code i did is

```
var currentname = "";
function getcurrentname() {
    $.get(
        url
    ).success(function(response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        currentname = response.name;
    });
}
getcurrentname();
console.log(currentname);
```

so what should i do use that variable globally.

Comment: `.get()` is asynchronous so your `console.log` is executed before the .`get()` finishes. Move the `console.log` into the success function.

Comment: then how will i be able to use that global variable.

Comment: Actually, you created a global variable in `JavaScript`. You are already using it globally. The only use of jQuery in your code is making an `asynchronous` call that, _when successful_ (hint), assigns a value to your variable.

Comment: i want to use response globally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You should use async : false in ajax request

Comment: any example for this.

Comment: No, you shouldn't, you should refactor the code to handle async.

Comment: You can use this code  $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async:false,
        complete: function (response) {
           response = JSON.parse(response);
           currentname = response.name;
        }
    });